# Unable to retrieve field value for async validation in a redux form

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux-form

It is how I set up my redux form

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form/immutable';
...

const asyncValidate = ( values, dispatch, props ) => {
  // print out the value for inspection
  console.log(`>>>> ${values.coupon}`);
}

...

const CheckoutForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'Checkout',
  asyncValidate,

})(cardDetailsForCheckoutForm);
```

The field I want to validate is called `coupon`. I need to validate it in an async manner because it requires a check on the server side. Somehow I cannot get the coupon value as `values.coupon`. It just returns as `undefined`

But according to the example (http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.1/examples/asyncValidation/), I should be able to retrieve the value. Why it fails?

Answer (score 0):

I find that after I restart the browser, the code works as expected.

Comment: You might simply want to delete your question

Comment: I think it is of some value. I spent a long time to track it down.